# Editing XML Attribute Causes a new node to be created

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

When I try and update a value in my XML document, instead of editing the existing value, it keeps inserting a new node with my new values.

If have tried this two ways with the same results...

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

XElement shippingElement = (from xml2 in doc
  .Elements("extradata").Elements("SharedCustomAppData")
  .Elements("clsNameValues").Elements("clsnamevalue")
where xml2.Element("name").Attribute("Value").Value == "SHOP_FLOOR_INSTR"
select xml2).FirstOrDefault();

shippingElement.Element("value").Attribute("Value").Value = "Changed!";
```

And

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(oLine.ExtraData);
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(
   "extradata/SharedCustomAppData/clsNameValues/clsnamevalue");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
XmlNode nameNode = node.SelectSingleNode("name");

if (nameNode != null && nameNode.Attributes["Value"].Value == "SHOP_FLOOR_INSTR")
{
    XmlNode valueNode = node.SelectSingleNode("value");

    if (valueNode != null)
    {
        valueNode.Attributes["Value"].Value = line.SHOP_FLOOR_INSTR;
    }
}
}
```

The section of XML I'm trying to update looks like this:

```
  <SharedCustomAppData>
   <clsNameValues>
     <clsnamevalue>
       <name Value="SHOP_FLOOR_INSTR" />
       <value Value="Current value" />
     </clsnamevalue>
   </clsNameValues>
 </SharedCustomAppData>
```

Comment: Your Linq to Xml code works fine on this xml. Can you show whole xml with *extradata* element?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the element name be "name" not "value" in the assignment statement?

try this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

XElement shippingElement = (from xml2 in doc
   .Elements("extradata").Elements("SharedCustomAppData")
   .Elements("clsNameValues").Elements("clsnamevalue")
where xml2.Element("name").Attribute("Value").Value == "SHOP_FLOOR_INSTR"
select xml2).FirstOrDefault();

shippingElement.Element("name").Attribute("Value").Value = "Changed!";
```

Comment: It's actually value. <value Value="Current value" />

value is the name of the node and Value is the value within it that I have to change. Not how I would have designed it but it's not something I can change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *System.Xml.XPath* extensions for Linq to Xml (I believe code will look shorter):

```
var expression = "//extradata/SharedCustomAppData/clsNameValues/clsnamevalue[name/@Value='SHOP_FLOOR_INSTR']/value";
XElement valueElement = xdoc.XPathSelectElement(expression);
if (valueElement != null)
    valueElement.SetAttributeValue("Value", "Changed!");
```

Also be careful with namespaces (it's not clear from your sample xml if there is some namespace declared on parent node).